# Is it possible to link historical data to specific date?

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to set up a matrix display that has a 8 quarters (36 months) look back of financial data. The problem I keep running into is that PBI either takes the most recent data and applies that to all the periods, or PBI has linking issues.

(https://imgur.com/a/ciLyt4A)

All the info for these 5 items are actually being pulled from the most recent date (6/19) and applying it backwards. These outputs should pull from the specific date.

See image.

I was hoping the data would be able to display according to the date in the Month end.

Comment: What is your source data, please show table/columns and some data so we understand what we are looking at

Comment: I can't show source data since it has confidential information. I believe I figured it out. The table relationship page needed to be tweaked.